# Rails/Paperclip/S3 How to upload numerous photos at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I've googled tutorials the last couple day on this and I'm completely lost/stuck.

I have my rails app working with paperclip and S3. I have an Image table, where a user can upload a single image, which will belong to an Album.

How can I get this so the user can upload more than one photo at once?

Heres my code: https://github.com/SirJustinWhite/PhotoCloud

Comment: You're asking volunteers to go read your code and come back with a solution. Instead perhaps you could just include the relevant section of code in your question, and also please let us know the error that you are getting.

Comment: Just curious: Did you get it working? And: Could you update your repo on GitHub? I would be interested in the solution you came up with.

Comment: I actually never got it to work. Maybe I'll give it another try now that some time has passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that you already have it working for one item. Getting it to work for multiple items is as easy as hitting the same working spot over and over again. There are many existing solutions to accomplish this. The one that I prefer to use is https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload . It works great for Rails, in fact, here is a example accomplishing what you want, using the same tools - https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example .

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is the method I'd like to implement.. using jQuery-File-Upload with Rails. The problem is, I dont understand how to implement it. Should I just clone into https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example and dig around to see how it was implemented, then add that to my app? Or maybe you could give me some guidance as to how I can implement. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a good approach - it should be clear to you without too much effort and frustration. You're probably more than 1/2 done already, just having the single version working.